# How to set transition from JavaScript while still inheriting style from CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I want to set `transform: translate(50px, 25px)` from JavaScript (I want to calculate 50 & 25 coordinates) to element `<div id="foo">bar</div>` and to inherit from CSS `#foo { transform: scale(.8) }`.

I explicitly want to have scale defined in CSS.

I would like to know if it's possible to override only one type of transform from JS without overwriting whole transform property. (example: like with margins; if you set in CSS margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px; you can directly access margin-top and change it without affecting other 3 sides).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `window.getComputedStyle` to read styles from CSS file. Read current transformation and apply with new one.

See how this works there:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lcjb5vLd/